# Auto height with dynamic height image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

I search a lot info about `height:auto` ,but I didnt find a solution for my problem. I need a full width image with dynamic height ,but that doesn't work :( Anyone can help!?

HTML:

```
<div id="roster">
<div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#roster{}

#roster .image{
    background-image:("http://nhlawyer.net/wp-content/uploads/header-image-2.jpg");
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

There is my [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5avkoqsL/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just use an actual image in the div..does that not work?

Comment: @Paulie_D _I need a full width image with dynamic height_
Actual image? how it is?

Comment: @Paulie_D when I change browser size ,image height changing. these are responsive design things ,but I dont know how to make this.

Comment: @Paulie_D then image shows in that height ,what I change ,but I dont need that. I need dynamic height.

Comment: background-size:cover;

Comment: @CarolMcKay that change only how image shows ,but as you see in my jsfiddle ,even height not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the image as `<img>` tag not as a `background-image` and by default if you make the image `width:100%;` its height will be auto

```css
#roster img{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="roster">
  <img src="http://nhlawyer.net/wp-content/uploads/header-image-2.jpg">
</div>
```

If you are using the image as `background` you should give the element specific  height then you can handle the height of background by `background-size: cover;`

```css
#roster .image{
  height:50px;
  background-image:url("http://nhlawyer.net/wp-content/uploads/header-image-2.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="roster">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
#roster .image {
    background: url('https://nhlawyer.net/wp-content/uploads/header-image-2.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: _I need a full width image with dynamic height_ This solution doesn't work with dynamic height.